# Append WAV Header in NAudio

Tags: c#, header, wav, naudio

I am trying to convert audio MP3 files to WAV with a standard rate (48 KHz, 16 bits, 2 channels) by opening with "MediaFoundationReaderRT" and specifying the standard settings in it.

After the file is converted to PCM WAV, when I try to play the WAV file, it gives corrupt output:

**Option 1 -**

```
WaveStream activeStream = new MediaFoundationReaderRT([Open "MyFile.mp3"]);
WaveChannel32 waveformInputStream = new WaveChannel32(activeStream);

waveformInputStream.Sample += inputStream_Sample;
```

I noticed that if I read the audio data into a memory stream (wherein it appends the WAV header via "WaveFileWriter"), then things work fine:

**Option 2 -**

```
WaveStream activeStream = new MediaFoundationReaderRT([Open "MyFile.mp3"]);

MemoryStream memStr = new MemoryStream();
byte[] audioData = new byte[activeStream.Length];
int bytesRead = activeStream.Read(audioData, 0, audioData.Length);
memStr.Write(audioData, 0, bytesRead);

WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(memStr, audioData);

RawSourceWaveStream rawSrcWavStr = new RawSourceWaveStream(activeStream, 
new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2));
WaveChannel32 waveformInputStream = new WaveChannel32(rawSrcWavStr);

waveformInputStream.Sample += inputStream_Sample;
```

However, reading the whole audio into memory is time-consuming. Hence I am looking at "Option 1" as noted above.

I am trying to figure out as to what exactly is the issue. Is it that the WAV header is missing which is causing the problem?

Is there a way in "Option 1" where I can append the WAV header to the "current playing" sample data, instead of converting the whole audio data into memory stream and then appending the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you need either of those options. Converting an MP3 file to WAV is quite simple with NAudio:

```
using(var reader = new MediaFoundationReader("input.mp3"))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("output.wav", reader);
}
```

And if you don't need to create a WAV file, then your job is already done - MediaFoundationReader already returns PCM from it's `Read` method so you can play it directly.

Comment: Thanks Mark, 

What I am looking at is, once MediaFoundationReader returns PCM from its Read method, I want to derive "2048 * 4" byte samples of data for the "current play position".

In this case, do I have to re-position again and again in MediaFoundationReader and read that data?

Comment: You can easily reposition in `MediaFoundationReader` during playback. The `CurrentTime` helper on the base class makes this even easier

Comment: So I want the decoded PCM bytes corresponding to "CurrentTime". In that case, I would position "WaveStream" to "CurrentTime". And then, how many minimum bytes of the decoded PCM frame have to be read to get the decoded data? Is it "16384 * 4"?